# How did the Parshiyot get their names

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, hebrew

and what are the names' significance?

Thanks

Naomi

---

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [Where are the rules for naming parshiyot explained?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10942/where-are-the-rules-for-naming-parshiyot-explained)

Comment: Naomi, welcome to the site, and thanks for your question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. This question seems to be an exact duplicate of a previously asked question, so I've closed this one; if you intended something different from the other question, by all means edit this question to better represent what you mean and someone will reopen it. I suggest, incidentally, that you register your username: it will afford you a better site experience.