# Parasha named after Balak?

Tags: names, parsha-torah-portion, parashas-yisro, reward-punishment, parashat-balak

I've heard from Harav Mansour Shelit"a as well as other Hachamim that Yitro was rewarded by getting a Parasha named by him. With that in mind, why did Balak get a Parasha named after him?

Comment: That's not R' Mansour; that's [Rashi](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=18&mefaresh=rashi).

Comment: What about Noach Pinchas and Sarah?

Comment: FWIW the [gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=14b&format=pdf) calls it Parashat Bil'am not Parashat Balak.

Comment: By "parashah of Bil'am" it may mean the *section* (pesuchah/stumah) of Bil'am, i.e. not the entire sidra as we know it.

Comment: @ba that's why I say "as well as other Hachamim". I was sure there was a source, but not sure where.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10942/where-are-the-rules-for-naming-parshiyot-explained?lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Due to the fact that Rus came from him, who is the for-bearer of Dovid HaMelech and Mashiach. ([Source](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51136&pgnum=169), [source](http://www.kaduri.net/?CategoryID=264&ArticleID=1560).)
2. Balak realized that everything is controlled by Hashem. ([Source](http://www.kaduri.net/?CategoryID=264&ArticleID=1560).)

Comment: Fascinating! Would you please update the source of answer #2? The link is broken

Answer (score 3):

What [Rashi](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=18&mefaresh=rashi) actually says regarding Yisro is that a parasha was added because of him. [Thus](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9879/showrashi/true):

> יתר, על שם שיתר פרשה אחת בתורה (להלן פסוק כא) ואתה תחזה.
>
> [He was called] Jether (יֶתֶר) because he [caused] a section to be added (יִתֵּר) to the Torah [namely]: “But you shall choose” (below verse 21).

This was drawn from the Sifrei on Behaalotecha.

In the popular retelling of this midrash, this was that he Yisro a parsha **named** after him. It is worthy to point out the difference between *parasha* and *sidra* in the language of Chazal. A *parasha* is the Biblical text from one gap to the next (*petuchot* and *setumot*), or in another context, the Torah portion of Eretz Yisrael, where they finished once every three years. Meanwhile, the term *sidra* refers to the Torah portion they read in Bavel, and which we read, in which we finish every year.

I don't think there is any need to justify the popular retelling of this, in which it is naming rather than adding, and it is the modern redefinition of parasha rather than Chazal's use of the term.

Besides that Chazal called it parashat Bilaam, as Double AA noted, the naming of parshiyot generally come from their opening words, and we need not find special merit to Balak.