# Significance of Parshas Noach, Chayei Sarah, Yisro, Korach, Balak, and Pinchas

Tags: parashat-noach, parashas-yisro, parashat-chaye-sara, parashat-balak, parshat-korach

This question was asked regarding Parshas Balak ([Parasha named after Balak?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17456/parasha-named-after-balak)), however, I'd like to see a source or reason that explains why the Torah chose ***these 6 individuals*** to name the Parsha/Sedra after:

- Noach
- Sarah (Chayei Sarah)
- Yisro / Yitro
- Korach
- Balak
- Pinchas

There have been answers given for these Parshios individually (such as suggesting that Yisro was [an addition to the Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17488/17591), or [Korach's narcissism](https://www.thejewishstar.com/stories/Parshat-Korach-Why-a-parsha-is-namedKorach,1791)).

There must be a correlation and connection between these 6 individuals, perhaps connected as well to the fact that Moshe Rabbeinu had his name [taken out of Parshas Tetzaveh](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/346413/jewish/The-Missing-Moses.htm).

Comment: There also used to be a Parsha called Betzalel

Comment: Are there other people that you would have expected to have a parshah named after them that don’t? Are these characters insufficiently represented in the parshah that bears their name? Can you clarify what exactly is bothering you about these parsha names?

Comment: I once heard a D'var Torah that connected all of them together, explaining something along the lines that Korach wanted Kavod from priesthood, whereas Yisro, who came from being a priest, humbled himself, and counters Korach. And Pinchas represented the resolving of all these names or something. I'm having trouble remembering this D'var Torah, hence my post.

Comment: It is interesting that most are related to priesthood as you mentioned. Or related to slaughtering, Noach after the flood and Sarah dying after/because of the akeida.

Comment: "why the Torah chose these 6 individuals " - The Torah didn't choose, since the Parshiyos and their names are a much later convention. Still a fair question, though.

Comment: Related: "[Where are the rules for naming parshiyot explained](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10942/1368)"? "[Why are parshat Noach and parshat Toldot named that way](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10936/1368)"?

Comment: @simyou R Tzodok says that the naming of the parshiyos are a tradition. So what a later convention mean? Because it is not like the possukim in the torah which was split up by the church

Answer (score 3):

Just listened to shiur by Rabbi Eytan Feiner, who when giving it says that Chayei Sora even though it has a name in it, it not the list of parshiyos that are just names. So I am going to summarise the shiur and hopefully it is understandable.
He says that these 5 people all have in common a turning point in Klal, that excludes the spies and the egel since there is not one person who can represent them. Also Moshe is not given a parasha because Moshe symbolises so much and you can't isolate Moshe to one thing since he corresponds to so many millstones. Also Vayikra there is no name since the Rambam its a continuation of the Matan Torah experience so no major transition take place.
So we start with Noach there is a world before the mabul and a world after the mabul and the person who changes the course of time is Noach with the 7 Noachite Laws.
Next is Yisro where we go from just keeping the 7 Noachite Laws into the 613 Mitzvos. He represents that transition from Exodus to Matan Torah.
The next is Korach where he represents a new transition in Judaism Machlokes, but not just any Machlokes rather the first Machlokes where the Jews actively and loudly challenge the authority and leadership of Moshe.
Next is Balak where he got us right at the end of parashas Balak by getting away from our fabric of מה טובו being modest and destroys our fabric.
Finally is Pinchas where he destroyed and restore the destruction caused by Balak, and being the real leader.
All of these 5 represent a transition in Judaism.