# Where can I find titles/names for the Mizrahi sidrot / triennial pericopes of Torah?

Tags: names, eretz-yisrael, torah-reading

I'm tracking down the "triennial pericopes" (*sidrot*) from the introduction to Ginsburg's *massorah*, also [listed in the Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13640-sidra), and thus I have the beginning and ending verses, but I'd like to find the titles or names traditionally used for them.

I'm assuming a table of names must exist like the (now dominant) Babylonian yearly *parashiyot* (annual pericopes) have titles *Bereshit*, *Noach*, *Lekh Lekha*, etc. The first significant words are not as obvious, and sometimes would collide with existing ones in the *sidrot* in some cases (Gen 2:4, 3:22, 5:1, 8:1, 8:15, 9:18). Gen. 9:18 is especially hard to choose significant words.

The source of the list I'm working with is said to be based on a manuscript from Yemen, with 167 sidrot, but I cannot find the original text, which I had hoped might include names/catch words by which to call them. I understand that in Eretz Yisrael the custom was to read through Torah twice in 7 years, so I'd also be glad to find a table of the division in 175 pericopes.

[This related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10942/where-are-the-rules-for-naming-parshiyot-explained?rq=1) has some interesting information and links.