# Why do some editions of Sefer HaChinuch split Parashat Mishpatim in two?

Tags: mishpatim, sefer-hachinuch

I've noticed that some editions of Sefer Hachinuch (such as [R. Chavel's edition](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) based on the 1523 Venice edition) split Parashat Mishpatim into two sections.

The first starts from [the beginning of Parashat Mishpatim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=96&hilite=) and includes the 24 *mitzvot* until 'Im Kesef Talveh' ([Shemot 22:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.22.24?lang=bi)), and the second [picks up from there](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=119) and lists the 29 *mitzvot* until the beginning of Parashat Terumah.

**Why was it printed this way? Was there a variant Torah-reading practice that split (what we call) Parashat Mishpatim over two weeks?**

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37796/170 and the comments to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5766/170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there was such a custom. Traditionally, the Babylonian annual Torah reading cycle with which we are all familiar had four "checkpoints" to keep everyone roughly in sync: Nitzavim before Rosh Hashana, Devarim before Tisha Bav, Bamidbar before Shavuot, and Tzav before Pesach. If you were in a small town and didn't have a calendar, as long as you doubled up portions as necessary for those checkpoints you'd be ok and you wouldn't have to calculate too far ahead.

Now, Tzav before Pesach is not so practical during a leap year, so the checkpoint for leap years became Metzora. The mnemonic here is (OC 428:4) פקדו/סגרו ופסחו מנו ועצרו צומו וצלו קומו ותקעו.

In years when Simchat Torah is just before Shabbat on Thursday, but Pesach starts after Shabbat on Sunday or Tuesday, there is that one extra Shabbat between them and we have to split something to hit the checkpoint. If that year is not a leap year, we split Vayakhel and Pekudei apart. If that year is a leap year, then Vayakhel-Pekudei and Tzaria-Metzora are already split and there is no other double parsha before Metzora to split. In that case, the common contemporary practice is to read Metzora two weeks before Pesach and Acharei Mot just before Pesach. The checkpoint fails, but what option is there?

One option is two split a 'non-traditional' section from earlier over two weeks. In Provence, there was a practice to split Mishpatim in half, with the second week picking up at Im Kesef. This is the practice you see reflected in the Chinukh who lived in Provence. This custom is mentioned by [Avudarham](https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Hebrew_Calendar%2C_Order_of_Parashiot_and_Haftarot.82).

Comment: Thanks for this. It’s interesting that he would list the two halves of Mishpatim separately, but not the two halves of Nitzavim.

Comment: @JoelK [Indeed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108816/759)

Comment: But wouldn't splitting Mishpatim mess up all the checkpoints? Bamidbar would be read two weeks before Shavuot, not one week, etc.?

Comment: @הנער the opposite, splitting fixes the checkpoints, that's the whole point. "We" who don't do this in those years (סימן העו"ף) are one week early each time till we eventually split matot and masei

Comment: @DoubleAA wow I can't believe I've never noticed that! That happened in 5774; I am amazing at myself for not realizing that we read both Metzora and Bamidbar a week too early

Comment: @הנערהזה I bet 99% of people didn't realize so don't feel so bad :) btw i'm told mishpatim/imkesef continued in algeria all the way till the end of the community there in the 1970s. Also btw other communities in europe would split other parshas besides mishpatim

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. There was a variant practice that split Parshat Mishpatim into two Parshiot. I saw that explained in the commentary on the Sefer HaChinuch.

Comment: please add a link or a quote