# Parsha Terumah and Shekalim

Tags: parashat-teruma

It appears that Parsha Terumah is read on Shabbat Shekalim only if it is also Rosh Chodesh. Can someone confirm this? This will occur next year (5785). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct.

We can limit ourselves to non-leap years, so Tzav will always be read on the last sabbath before Passover. Shekalim is always the 7th-to-last sabbath before Passover (4 special sections, 1 break week and 2 sabbaths in days 2-14 of Nissan or, if Adar began on Friday, 2 break weeks and 1 Sabbath in days 2-14 of Nissan). Accordingly, the only way Terumah will be Shekalim is if Vayaqhel and Pekudei are separated in a non-leap year which only happens in [that configuration with the extra week before Passover](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/112106/759) which in a non-leap year means Passover starting on Sunday and hence Adar starting on Shabbat.

The opposite case (Terumah on Rosh Chodesh without Shekalim) can happen on Rosh Chodesh Adar I in a leap year.